# Regular expression for constant number in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Regular expression to find integer constants like `10_000_000`

I've tried with:

```
regex = /^[+-]?[0-9]{1}[0-9_]*/

regex.match '10_000_000' #=> 10_000_000

regex.match '10__000_00' #=> 10__000_000
```

I want that with `10__000_00` does not match anything, for continuous underscores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^[+-]?[0-9]+(?:_[0-9]+)*$
```

#### Online Demo: http://rubular.com/r/9R6hrtNw6W

Answer (score 0):

I would do as below:

```
regex = /^(\d+_\d+)+$/
regex.match '10_000_000'
#=> #<MatchData "10_000_000" 1:"0_000">
regex.match '10__000_000'
#=> nil
```